# Sending command from Handphone to Laptop using J2ME and Bluetooth

Tags: java, java-me, reference, bluetooth

I have a question, I want to connect my handphone with my ubuntu laptop using bluetooth connection. The handphone just need to send what key I pressed to the laptop and do process based on what key I pressed. Did you guys have any *easy to learn* reference about j2me and bluetooth for people who just know basic JAVA syntax?

Comment: There is lots of good info on writing bluetooth applications for mobile phones in Java. As long as you know how to do the ubuntu side, a simple google search will result in several tutorials and instructions on the mobile side.

Comment: yes... Mobile side is easier than Ubuntu side I guess

Comment: yes, I've been successfully implementing the mobile side. I throw the question here because I can't implement it in ubuntu side:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may start from [this](http://www.codeguru.com/java/article.php/c13147). Most of the initial activities are implemented in this code.